# I can not start the player in my code

Tags: java, jmf

I am trying to launch my my code and start the player. But I can not do that.

```
import javax.media.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MP3Player {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       File file = new File("c://player/trigger.mpg");
       MediaLocator mrl = new MediaLocator(file.toURL());
       Player player = Manager.createPlayer(mrl);
       player.start();
    }

}
```

**[Edit by Philipp]**
According to a comment by the original author, Netbeans prints the following error message:

```
Unable to handle format: MPEG, 160x120, FrameRate=30.0, Length=28800 Failed to realize:
com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@131f71a Error: Unable to realize
com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@131f71a BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**[/Edit by Philipp]**

Comment: Is the missing / in the path a typo?

Comment: "can not do that" = ? Are you getting an error? Is your computer exploding?

Comment: I got this message from Netbeans

Comment: Unable to handle format: MPEG, 160x120, FrameRate=30.0, Length=28800
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@131f71a
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@131f71a
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JMF player at all, but I assume the problem is that the code exits immediately after issuing the command, terminating any other threads...

I'd try inserting a Thread.sleep(1000); after player.start(); :

```
public class MP3Player {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {    
        File file = new File("c:/player/trigger.mpg");    
        MediaLocator mrl = new MediaLocator(file.toURL());    
        Player player = Manager.createPlayer(mrl);    
        player.start(); 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
}
```

If now the first second of the MP3 is heard, this was the issue.

**EDIT** Also, someone pointed out problems with the slashes, the path should be correct too, but the slash is not missing, but there is rather one too much of it...

**EDIT2** Ok, I misread mpg for mp3, and as the poster posted the error he got: the format of the video is not supported by JMF, you need a codec.

This might be of help: [Tek-tips: Play MPEG-4 movie with JMF?](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=978659)

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to handle format: MPEG, 160x120, FrameRate=30.0`
It is unable to play a **video stream** it founds. From the description and the name of your code, the file is expected to contain only **audio streams** of the compression format MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer III). *An .mpg extension may contains lot of different mpeg formats*